# Unable to deploy simple nodejs + mysql application on redhat openshit - running out of quota

Tags: openshift, redhat

I have simple `nodejs + mysql` application and trying to migrate over to `Redhat Openshift` free account that provides `2 core CPUs and 1 Gb memory`. I'm not able to install both as nodejs install is taking up both CPU and all the memory (note that I needed to select 1 GB memory for node app as selecting lower value is causing issues). My node app may not need 1 gb after initial build but not able to downscale to release memory - running into issues (pls refer below for more details). Also, is there a way to downscale to 1 cpu for node app to create room for mysql app. Any help appreciated.

Further details:

While installing node app I selected 1 Gb memory. The app builds and deploys fine but after deployment I see node app end up using both both CPUs.

When trying to install mysql running into out of quota issue.

`You are at your quota for CPU (limit) on pods.You can still create deployment config 'mysql' but no pods will be created until resources are freed`

When I try to downscale node app to reduce memory manually the build is failing - get stuck with following

`--> Scaling up dev3-2 from 0 to 1, scaling down dev3-1 from 1 to 0 (keep 1 pods available, don't exceed 2 pods)
    Scaling dev3-2 up to 1
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-p6mlq" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-rcwxc" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-m667b" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-j28gz" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-dwsz5" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-2xrvz" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-hwk8k" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-hrjk8" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 Error creating: pods "dev3-2-8lts5" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
-->  FailedCreate: dev3-2 (combined from similar events): Error creating: pods "dev3-2-74xzp" is forbidden: exceeded quota: compute-resources, requested: limits.cpu=1,limits.memory=512Mi, used: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi, limited: limits.cpu=2,limits.memory=1Gi
error: timed out waiting for "dev3-2" to be synced`

Answer (score 3):

Set the deployment strategy to Recreate instead of Rolling. At the point of changing it, you may need to scale down to 0 replicas and then scale back up to 1, to get it past state where was trying to use Rolling.

Also, memory needed for build is under a separate quota than that for running application. So you can quite happily have memory limit on build config at 1Gi. Your deployment of application you would use 512Mi for each of node and MySQL.